# Twitter iframe tracking with gtm

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Please advise how to track clicks on a twitter widget iframe through gtm for google analytics.

A Step by step process would be fine.

I know that i need to set events for the tag but my first need is to populate html elements to dataLayer.

But so far,  as an **iframe**, the link click listener doesn't record anything.

Here is the widget:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   You will need to edit your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: I'm a bit baffled, how would a jpg image of a widget help with code integration ? Plus, was DaImto said.

Comment: I suspect you're not going to get the answer that you're looking for. Iframes are windows to another internet location; in order to get data from them you have to insert code into the location that you're referencing, which means that you have to control that location, which I doubt is the case here.

Comment: Tks J Brazier . I have to use this snippet but i don't know how to implement it : https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events.See the chapter "Detecting Events for Web Analytics"

Answer (score 0):

@DalmTO: nothing i 'm afraid just auditing the fact that under tag manager debug mode, with  gtm.linkclick  listener the dataLayer record any  variable from this widget
@Eike Pierstorff : it was just to display what i'm talking about :) . As this kind of widget seems to be popular so maybe it could help ..sorry. Otherwise, find enclosed another screenshot but regarding the iframe syntax. as the code is very long i just send over an excerpt through a screenshot.[iframe code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK7FB.jpg)
Thanks a lot for you help.